# Права сохранения для файла

Tags: linux, ubuntu, chmod

как сделать что б сохраняло файл

вот такое пишет:

> ```
> Unable to save file: Permission denied         '/var/www/html/worldofgold.zzz.com.ua/index.php'
> ```

Comment: вы права для папки задайте , надо зайти под root и открыть права , может быть кто то по другому как то решает но я из под GKSU это всё делаю

Comment: спасибо, просто поставил chmod

Comment: так и надо было ... но я сразу открывал доступ на  var/www/html/

Comment: @МаксимЛенский, так делать не надо.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin почему ? это я у себя делаю так , ни первый день на Линуксе , знаю как избежать косяков ...

Comment: @МаксимЛенский, «у себя» можно делать что угодно. это не предосудительно. давать же вредные советы другим — плохо.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin  пояснил бы лучше .. что не так ... линукс это не виндоус ... сколько раз открывал доступ ни разу ни чего не было ... даже в сеть пускал и ни чего не случилось

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот так через терминал сделать надо било:

```
sudo chmod -R 777 /var/www
```

Comment: вредный совет. не рекомендую им пользоваться.

Comment: почему же вредний совет?

Comment: чем он вреден ? из ВНЕ доступа нету к директории ... да и не выйдет в сеть ... проблем не должно быть .. это ни сервер

Comment: @МаксимЛенский, Ostap34PHP, потому что все файлы в этом каталоге станут доступны для изменения/удаления всем пользователям системы.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin каким пользователям то ? я один пользуюсь но ... я понимаю что есть некие демоны в системе но это фигня

Comment: @МаксимЛенский, *но это фигня* — для **вас** — возможно. но не для всех других, кто прочитает данные вопрос и вредный ответ.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin не придумывайте .. если бы автор написал бы что у него сервер я бы не за что такой совет бы не дал бы ..

Comment: @МаксимЛенский, этот вопрос и ответ доступны любому пользователю сети интернет. не только автору вопроса. вредные советы на этом сайте, к счастью, не приветствуются. // у автора вопроса именно сервер (на котором работает как минимум какая-то реализация http-сервера), хотя это никак не влияет на ситуацию.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/61865/discussion-between---and-alexander-barakin).